# What revision my local working copy is based on (SVN)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I don't know SVN very well and google didn't help me either.

I have a folder and would like to know which revision this working copy is based on. How do I get this information? I have seen there are several commands where I can get the revision, but I am not sure which revision is the one I am looking for.

1 For example, with the `svnversion "myPath"` command, I get a range of revisions.

`4212:4168MS` Does this output mean that my working copy is based on revision 4212?

2 Or when I use the `info` command. What means the line `Revision: 66593` and what says the line `Last Changed Rev: 66591`? Is `Revision` the "Head"-Revision, this means the newest revision on the repository and is `Last Changed Rev` mean, that my working copy is based in this revision?

```
$ svn info
Path: .
URL: https://svn.example.com/svn/myproject/trunk
Repository Root: https://svn.example.com/svn/
Repository UUID: d2a7a951-c712-0410-832a-9abccabd3052
Revision: 66593
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: bnguyen
Last Changed Rev: 66591
Last Changed Date: 2008-09-11 18:25:27 +1000 (Thu, 11 Sep 2008)
```

3 Is there perhaps a file in the .svn folder where I get the revision my working copy is based on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [SVNBook | Subversion Working Copies](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc).

> 1 For example, with the svnversion "myPath" command, I get a range of
>   revisions.
>
> 4212:4168MS Does this output mean that my working copy is based on
>   revision 4212?

Did you take this example from [SVNBook | `svnversion`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html)? This particular example means that you have a mixed-revision working copy (some files were updated to different revisions manually), it includes local modifications and some path or paths in your working copy were switched to another URL.

> 2 Or when I use the info command. What means the line Revision: 66593
>   and what says the line Last Changed Rev: 66591? Is Revision the
>   "Head"-Revision, this means the newest revision on the repository and
>   is Last Changed Rev mean, that my working copy is based in this
>   revision?

Your working copy is at `Revision: 66593` and it was checked out from the following URL: `https://svn.example.com/svn/myproject/trunk`. The most recent revision that changed `/svn/myproject/trunk` is 66591.

Here is an example. Here you can see that the working copy is at revision 58798 (the latest one in my testing repository). However, the latest commit that made changes to `/MyRepoExport/branches/1.13.x` is 28722.

```
Working Copy Root Path: C:\wcs\1.13.x
URL: https://localhost/repos/MyRepoExport/branches/1.13.x
Relative URL: ^/branches/1.13.x
Repository Root: https://localhost/repos/MyRepoExport
Repository UUID: 3313e9ec-a0ff-7d43-b846-2f41dc5c0441
Revision: 28798
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: stefankueng
Last Changed Rev: 28722
Last Changed Date: 2020-01-29 21:27:41 +0300 (Wed, 29 Jan 2020)
```

> 3 Is there perhaps a file in the .svn folder where I get the revision
>   my working copy is based on?

You don't need to examine contents of the pristine area (`.svn` directory) unless your are a developer of Subversion.